# How does Java and other managed languages achieve any performance, if everything is allocated at random places of the heap?

Tags: java, optimization, caching, heap, high-performance

### Prelude

Recently, I helped a friend of mine in coding him a problem for his university Algorithms course, where problems are submitted in Java. I sent him code with good O notation complexity, sequential memory accesses (as I thought) and etc, all the common in C++ world good practices, and kept hitting Time Limit Exceeded message. **This is not an attempt to start a war about programming languages.**

### Known issues

However, sequential memory accesses when iterating over an `ArrayList<SomeClass>` (which I thought is as simple as going over `std::vector<SomeStruct>` in C++) turned out to be not as fast as I wanted it to be, due to reasons we all know:

1. Each separate element of the `ArrayList` is stored in some arbitrary place of the heap (potentially not sequential at all?)
2. Some of the allocations (not all, but some of them) require an actual system call to get memory from OS to create an instance of `SomeClass` (well, it's partially solved with memory pools, and might be solved in some way with Project Valhalla [JEP-401](https://openjdk.org/jeps/401))
3. And even after all that generics in Java work in a way that `ArrayList` *actually* stores pointers to `Object`s, so on each call of `SomeClass`'s method, CPU has to go to v-table, check type (potentially branch-predicted?), and only after all that call correct method.
4. Bound-checks in array (probably branch-predicted or JIT optimized?)
5. Also, sometimes daemon-thread like garbage collector kicks in, and spends some of the time resources of the program

After thinking on it for a while, I have no idea how developers in banks, some HFT companies (!!!), stock markets and other businesses that require high performance, manage to write fast (**not "fast enough"**, but *really* fast, competing) code in Java.

### Question

I can understand how anything can be optimized by out-of-order execution on CPU, smart allocator, and JIT, except for the memory-access patern: How does Java, and other managed languages, get **any** performance, if everything is at random places of a heap [or they aren't random?], everything is non-sequential [is it?] and therefore each memory access, even in "sequential" `ArrayList` is a cache miss?

Comment: why are you sure that complexity was adequate? Cache locality and branch prediction are studied and required in advanced courses not in Algorithms

Comment: @Basilevs because I know that O(NlogN) where N < 10^5 with 1 second Time Limit is an easy one with decent memory access pattern.

Comment: Welp, then I assume professor has forgot to implement warmup stage of tests. Happens to the best of us. The course is probably new.

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of point 2.  Is the creation of the objects part of the timing?  It's not obvious how object instantiation relates to iterating over an ArrayList.

Comment: @JimmyJames filling up an ArrayList has much to do with allocation

Comment: @blonded04 Iterating over an array is not filling an array.  Are you including the time to create and populate the array in the timing?  That's fine, but you should be clear about what you are measuring.

Comment: Also, w/ regard to point 2.  The OS allocates memory for the heap when the heap needs to grow but JRE doesn't need to interact with the OS to uses that allocated memory e.g., for new objects within already allocated heap space, unless your objects allocate non heap memory as with JNI.

Comment: 1 and 3 are basically talking about the same thing.  IIRC, arrays are sequential in the heap but the references in that array point to objects that can be anywhere on the heap.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if we could see the code.  It's possible the performance issue is due to something not related to what you've explained here.  For example, if you are including the ArrayList creation/population time, one simple performance hack is to use an initial capacity when creating the ArrayList as explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-). The time it takes to create a new array and copy all the elements into it multiple times is a waste.  Ideally, if you know what the final size wil be, use that.

Comment: If you’re interested in more answers and a better reception consider making an edit that doesn’t invite an unbounded list of Java optimizations. The site doesn’t handle list questions well. We can talk about specific optimizations or a general discipline to follow when optimizing.

Comment: @candied_orange thank you, I edited the question so that know I ask how Java gets any performance, if everything is on a heap and [potentially] not sequential and therefore is a cache miss

Comment: @Basilevs fixed, thank you

Comment: Realistically: most people don't care about cache locality in any language. Those that do use different data structures. May I present the LMAX Disruptor: https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/user-guide/index.html

Comment: (also, if you're helping someone else cheat on their homework, there is no way Java *students* would be expected to care about cache locality, and there is something else performance-wise wrong that you've not spotted)

Comment: @pjc50 thank you very much for such a useful link! i'm not helping someone to cheat everyday and it turned out that because course is new and and teacher just poorly ported problem from reference all-languages contest :D

Comment: @blonded04 oh, so they set the timeout value such that all solutions would fail? (e.g. before JVM startup time)

Comment: @pjc50 no, everything is not that bad :), their uni TA said that he was in hurry and blindly copied that problem, that problem shouldn't even been in that homework

Comment: @blonded04 anyway, a key insight you need is that very few Java users are bound by raw CPU use as an important consideration. Most Java - in fact I suspect most server-side code - is of the form "retrieve a small number of records from DB or another API and process them lightly". Cache locality works because the code is working with the objects it just created, and most of the request-based unit of work fits in cache.

Comment: In long-running allocation-heavy programs, Java-style compacting GC can lead to much better memory locality than comparable C++ programs that would suffer from increasing memory fragmentation. Java's heap is more like the C++ stack in many ways, just without the lifetime limitations. Or like an arena allocator. Objects created in order are likely to occupy adjacent addresses. Of course there's no free lunch. You still have pointer indirection, and will need ca 2× memory.

Answer (score 4):

> After thinking on it for a while, I have no idea how developers in banks, some HFT companies (!!!), stock markets and other businesses that require high performance, manage to write fast (not "fast enough", but really fast, competing) code in Java.

Fast enough is fast enough. These are businesses. You don't blindly reach for speed if you want to stay in business. A little thing called [the law of diminishing returns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminishing_returns) will bankrupt you faster than any competitor if you ignore practicality. Focus on the speed you need. Measure. Profile. Decide if you really care.

You seem really averse to indirection. Understand that indirection can speed you up if the alternative is moving copies around. Don't assume you know which is faster without evidence. Yes, indirection comes at a cost. Making things sequential comes at a cost as well.

> Recently, I helped a friend of mine in coding him a problem for his university Algorithms course, where problems are submitted in Java. I sent him code with good O notation complexity, sequential memory accesses (as I thought) and etc, all the common in C++ world good practices, and kept hitting Time Limit Exceeded message. This is not an attempt to start a war about programming languages.

Java isn't C++. Not all the C++ tricks work in Java.

If you were hoping for a list of Java tricks you should know that we regularly close [list questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/why-do-some-examples-and-list-of-things-questions-get-closed).

> performance, if everything is at random places of a heap [or they aren't random?] , everything is non-sequential [is it?] and therefore each memory access, even in "sequential" ArrayList is a cache miss?

I can’t predict everything but
I think there are some fundamental misunderstandings here.

What prevents a cache miss isn’t being sequential (or even [contiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812677/is-the-java-heap-memory-contiguous)). It’s having a footprint that fits in a cache page (and the luck to get that footprint placed on only one page).

A random ordering wouldn’t change the size of the footprint. What might is interleaving different object types together. There’s no predicting this behavior under the Java spec. This is up to the flavor of JVM you ran this on.

The most reliable way to cause a cache miss is to allocate and access more than a cache page of memory.

Comment: You can answer closed questions?  Interesting, but is that how things are supposed to be done?

Comment: @JimmyJames there's a race condition where if you start writing an answer before the question is closed there is a window in which you can still post the answer. It's not considered important enough to fix (which I agree with as a decision, not that anyone cares what I think)

Comment: @PhilipKendall I got a pop-up in the browser when I was writing my answer.  Does that mean if I had submitted it would be posted anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Once profiling isolates a bottleneck following optimizations can be done:

- increase available memory
- vary garbage collection settings
- parallelize
- eliminate garbage collection by reusing objects
- use primitives and arrays instead of objects
- delegate computations to other languages

Example:

`ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();`

becomes

`double[] x = new double[1000], y = new double[1000];`;